# How to change the value of window.navigator.webdriver by R?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

Current testing environment:
1)Selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59
2)R 4.3, RSelenium 1.7.9
3)Chrome 107.0.5304.122(32-bit)
4）Chromedriver107.0.5304.62 (32bit)
5)Os:windows 10

I want to make value of window.navigator.webdriver as FALSE.

I looking forward to getting guidance,thank!